# Using circle math for solid collision

Tags: javascript, physics, collision, geometry

```
    function distance(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
            var x = x1 - x2;
            var y = y1 - y2;
            return(Math.sqrt((x*x) + (y*y)))   
    };

    function collisionCirc(circ1, circ2) {
            var d = distance(circ1.x, circ1.y, circ2.x, circ2.y);
            var r = circ1.radius + circ2.radius;
            return(r > d);
    };

    function collisionCircPoint(circ1, circ2) {
            var cx = ((circ1.x * circ2.radius) + (circ2.x * circ1.radius)) / (circ1.radius + circ2.radius);
            var cy = ((circ1.y * circ2.radius) + (circ2.y * circ1.radius)) / (circ1.radius + circ2.radius);
            var p = [cx, cy];
            return p;
    };

    function angleDegrees(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
            return (Math.atan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1) * 180 / Math.PI) + 180;
    };

    function updateCollisions() {
            var a;
            var p;

            Player.hitArea = new PIXI.Circle(Player.sprite.x, Player.sprite.y, 20);
            MapObjects.chest.hitArea = new PIXI.Circle(MapObjects.chest.x, MapObjects.chest.y, 20);

            if (collisionCirc(Player.hitArea, MapObjects.chest.hitArea)) {
                a = angleDegrees(Player.sprite.x, Player.sprite.y, MapObjects.chest.x, MapObjects.chest.y);
                p = collisionCircPoint(Player.hitArea, MapObjects.chest.hitArea);
                        Player.sprite.x = p[0];
                        Player.sprite.y = p[1];
            };

    };
```

I have 2 sprites on the map and each has a circle hitArea defined. I am trying to make a smooth circular collision that the player cannot pass through. I thought I could just set the Player.sprite's coordinates to the point of collision but it just warps him to the MapObjects.chest's coordinates, even though the point of collision is correct and is 20 pixels from the MapObject.chest's center. What am I doing wrong or what more information is needed to create a collision much like the JavaScript physics libraries where I can circle around a circle object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The collision point is between the player and the obstacle. If you move the player towards the collision point, you are actually moving the player closer. For example, if there's exactly 40 px (r1+r2) between the player and the obstacle, the collision point is between them, at only 20 px from the obstacle!

When you have multiple objects, getting it right when the collision has already happened is difficult. If there is only one obstacle nearby, you can simply move the player directly away from the obstacle. However, this way the player might actually end up inside another obstacle.

Another solution is to go back to the start and try smaller movements, until there is no collision. This way you would eventually get it right, but this might also be slow.

The mathematically correct solution is to calculate the maximum distance to move before the collision happens. This is done by solving the following vector equation:

```
# p = player position before moving
# o = obstacle position
# u = player direction (unit vector)
# d = distance to move
distance(o, p + d * u) = o.radius + p.radius
```

That's mathematics, you may solve it by yourself or using a tool like Wolfram Alpha.

Solving this equation will give you zero, one or two possible values for the distance. Negative values you can dismiss, as they mean that the player is already past the obstacle. If you get only one value, it means that the player would merely brush the obstacle, which you can also dismiss. Two values mean that the collision happens between these distances; the smaller value is where the collision starts, and the larger value is where the player would already be through the obstacle. Also, if one value is positive and the other is negative, it means that the player is already inside the obstacle, which should never happen.

You should run this check for all nearby obstacles and then move the player according to the smallest non-negative result (that is, zero or positive), or less, if the player can't move that fast.

Finally, to circle around a round object, you can move the player a little bit in a perpendicular direction (either left or right, depending on which side of the obstacle the player will be passing) after a collision, if this doesn't cause any new collisions.

There are many other possible implementations.

Answer (score 0):

```
        Player.hitArea = new PIXI.Circle(Player.sprite.x, Player.sprite.y, 20);
        MapObjects.chest.hitArea = new PIXI.Circle(MapObjects.chest.x, MapObjects.chest.y, 20);
        if (collisionCirc(Player.hitArea, MapObjects.chest.hitArea)) {
            p = collisionCircPoint(Player.hitArea, MapObjects.chest.hitArea);
            a = angleDegrees(Player.sprite.x, Player.sprite.y, MapObjects.chest.x, MapObjects.chest.y);
                if (Player.sprite.x - MapObjects.chest.x > 0) {
                    Player.sprite.x += 1;
                } else  if (Player.sprite.x + MapObjects.chest.x > 0) {
                    Player.sprite.x -= 1;
                };
                if (Player.sprite.y - MapObjects.chest.y > 0) {
                    Player.sprite.y += 1;
                } else  if (Player.sprite.y + MapObjects.chest.y > 0) {
                    Player.sprite.y -= 1;
                };
            };
        };
```

I added that and it actually works well enough minus the player speed being slightly too fast when running into the MapObjects.chest's hitArea at certain angles. Work on that later.